# Stackoverflow UI widgets to delete several of your own answers or questions at once?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, answers

For instance,

[image]

I will gladly close my question if it has been asked before, thanks!

Comment: Why would this ever be a good idea?

Comment: Ah, the auto-ban feature-request.

Comment: @random, It's quicker than having to navigate to each individual page.

Comment: Don't mind the downvotes, by the way; on meta, they signify agreement or disagreement.

Comment: @mre might I inquire as to why you'd want to delete that many questions/answers at once? Perhaps there is something more involved that solves the ultimate problem at hand here.

Comment: @mre oh, and please tell me it isn't for farming the Unsung Hero badge :-(

Comment: @corsiKa, I'm not fishing for badges.

Comment: @mre fair enough - but what is the reason that you'd want to delete content in mass amounts?

Comment: @corsiKa, for reasons of ease-of-use

Comment: @meeting that's why you want this feature. I'm asking why would you want to delete questions in the first place?

Comment: @corsiKa, there are instances where another person has supplied a better and/or more precise answer than me and i want to remove my answer since i view it as clutter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deletion is never encouraged. Even if the content is bad, you are encouraged to try to fix it, and others will always try to improve it. If it's a decent question but not a good fit for the Q&A format, it'll be closed to prevent further answers. Only if it's not salvageable will deletion become an option.

Keep in mind that as a programmer, your problems are the problems of others. I'm sure many of the problems you've faced aren't unique to you and your situations. That's the concept of Stack Overflow (and SE in general): encountering specific problems and finding solutions that will benefit the programming community as a whole.

If you're only here to get solutions to problems and don't want others to benefit from them, you are always able to delete a question from its page. But I urge you to consider whether this site may be for you if your attitude towards the website is one of self-benefit.

(I don't know why you'd want to delete helpful answers, though.)

Comment: I guess it comes down to personality...im personally insecure and paranoid and am constantly deleting answers/questions that i see painting me in a negative light

Comment: @mre: I get occasional downvotes on my answers. I used to be the *exact same way*--wanting to delete those answers because of them. Though you'll come to a point where you stop caring, only because you should be confident of the work you put out there, regardless of whether it's helped someone or not. Though I can't see why you'd be worried with 15,000 rep on SO.

Comment: If you have answers/questions you're not happy about, try to improve them instead. That's the best thing to do.

Comment: @mre: No problem, and good luck. :) I hope you find comfort in your answers, because as a programmer, I'm really affected when people are discouraged.

Comment: Yeah, as I get older, I'm becoming more and more inclined to improve upon my errors instead of pretending they never happened.

Answer (score 8):

That's a ... *bad* idea.

Why should we give users the ability to do something that is harmful to the ecosystem?  You make things easy that you want the users to do. I don't think anyone wants to make it easy to remove content from the system.  That's counter to the idea of a knowledge exchange.

Comment: I don't understand how this would be harmful to the ecosystem? It's already a part of the ecosystem...this would just automate the process of doing it in mass, no?...and content is never removed...although that's only apparent to users with a high enough reputation (which I also think is bogus and does exactly what you fear (i.e. "i don't think anyone wants to make it easy to remove content from the system")).

Comment: You do realize that this signals you have asked bad questions or gave bad answers, right? And that this might also factor in to a ban to answer questions or ask new questions? I can already see the "Why have I been banned? Might it have something to do with the 10 answers I just deleted?" questions popping up here on MSO.

Comment: @Bart, The rules around here seem backward, or maybe im just real dense and/or inexperienced.

Comment: @mre I don't think any of those is the case. Though I have yet to hear a valid reason to want to delete several questions or answers at once. I sincerely don't think there is one.